# How to compile doom on ubuntu?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, ubuntu, compilation

I am trying to compile the source code for the original doom as a way to learn C. I downloaded it from [github](https://github.com/id-Software/DOOM) and fixed an obvious mistake in i_video.c line 49 (errnos.h -> errno.h).

I now get this:

```
m_misc.c:257:5: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
m_misc.c:257:5: warning: (near initialization for ‘defaults[14].location’) [enabled by default]
m_misc.c:257:5: error: initializer element is not computable at load time
m_misc.c:257:5: error: (near initialization for ‘defaults[14].defaultvalue’)
m_misc.c:264:35: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
m_misc.c:264:5: error: initializer element is not constant
m_misc.c:264:5: error: (near initialization for ‘defaults[16].defaultvalue’)
m_misc.c:265:37: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
m_misc.c:265:5: error: initializer element is not constant
m_misc.c:265:5: error: (near initialization for ‘defaults[17].defaultvalue’)
m_misc.c:288:45: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
m_misc.c:288:5: error: initializer element is not constant
m_misc.c:288:5: error: (near initialization for ‘defaults[31].defaultvalue’)
m_misc.c:289:45: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
m_misc.c:289:5: error: initializer element is not constant
m_misc.c:289:5: error: (near initialization for ‘defaults[32].defaultvalue’)
m_misc.c:290:45: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
m_misc.c:290:5: error: initializer element is not constant
m_misc.c:290:5: error: (near initialization for ‘defaults[33].defaultvalue’)
m_misc.c:291:45: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
m_misc.c:291:5: error: initializer element is not constant
m_misc.c:291:5: error: (near initialization for ‘defaults[34].defaultvalue’)
m_misc.c:292:45: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
m_misc.c:292:5: error: initializer element is not constant
m_misc.c:292:5: error: (near initialization for ‘defaults[35].defaultvalue’)
m_misc.c:293:45: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
m_misc.c:293:5: error: initializer element is not constant
m_misc.c:293:5: error: (near initialization for ‘defaults[36].defaultvalue’)
m_misc.c:294:45: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
m_misc.c:294:5: error: initializer element is not constant
m_misc.c:294:5: error: (near initialization for ‘defaults[37].defaultvalue’)
m_misc.c:295:45: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
m_misc.c:295:5: error: initializer element is not constant
m_misc.c:295:5: error: (near initialization for ‘defaults[38].defaultvalue’)
m_misc.c:296:45: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
m_misc.c:296:5: error: initializer element is not constant
m_misc.c:296:5: error: (near initialization for ‘defaults[39].defaultvalue’)
m_misc.c:297:45: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
m_misc.c:297:5: error: initializer element is not constant
m_misc.c:297:5: error: (near initialization for ‘defaults[40].defaultvalue’)
m_misc.c: In function ‘M_LoadDefaults’:
m_misc.c:395:5: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
make: *** [linux/m_misc.o] Error 1
```

in the m_misc.c file during this declaration on the lines that contain casts:

```
default_t   defaults[] =
{
    {"mouse_sensitivity",&mouseSensitivity, 5},
    {"sfx_volume",&snd_SfxVolume, 8},
    {"music_volume",&snd_MusicVolume, 8},
    {"show_messages",&showMessages, 1},


#ifdef NORMALUNIX
    {"key_right",&key_right, KEY_RIGHTARROW},
    {"key_left",&key_left, KEY_LEFTARROW},
    {"key_up",&key_up, KEY_UPARROW},
    {"key_down",&key_down, KEY_DOWNARROW},
    {"key_strafeleft",&key_strafeleft, ','},
    {"key_straferight",&key_straferight, '.'},

    {"key_fire",&key_fire, KEY_RCTRL},
    {"key_use",&key_use, ' '},
    {"key_strafe",&key_strafe, KEY_RALT},
    {"key_speed",&key_speed, KEY_RSHIFT},

// UNIX hack, to be removed. 
#ifdef SNDSERV
    {"sndserver", (int *) &sndserver_filename, (int) "sndserver"},
    {"mb_used", &mb_used, 2},
#endif

#endif

#ifdef LINUX
    {"mousedev", (int*)&mousedev, (int)"/dev/ttyS0"},
    {"mousetype", (int*)&mousetype, (int)"microsoft"},
#endif

    {"use_mouse",&usemouse, 1}, 
    {"mouseb_fire",&mousebfire,0},
    {"mouseb_strafe",&mousebstrafe,1},
    {"mouseb_forward",&mousebforward,2},

    {"use_joystick",&usejoystick, 0}, 
    {"joyb_fire",&joybfire,0},
    {"joyb_strafe",&joybstrafe,1},
    {"joyb_use",&joybuse,3},
    {"joyb_speed",&joybspeed,2},

    {"screenblocks",&screenblocks, 9}, 
    {"detaillevel",&detailLevel, 0}, 

    {"snd_channels",&numChannels, 3}, 



    {"usegamma",&usegamma, 0},
    {"chatmacro0", (int *) &chat_macros[0], (int) HUSTR_CHATMACRO0 },
    {"chatmacro1", (int *) &chat_macros[1], (int) HUSTR_CHATMACRO1 },
    {"chatmacro2", (int *) &chat_macros[2], (int) HUSTR_CHATMACRO2 },
    {"chatmacro3", (int *) &chat_macros[3], (int) HUSTR_CHATMACRO3 },
    {"chatmacro4", (int *) &chat_macros[4], (int) HUSTR_CHATMACRO4 },
    {"chatmacro5", (int *) &chat_macros[5], (int) HUSTR_CHATMACRO5 },
    {"chatmacro6", (int *) &chat_macros[6], (int) HUSTR_CHATMACRO6 },
    {"chatmacro7", (int *) &chat_macros[7], (int) HUSTR_CHATMACRO7 },
    {"chatmacro8", (int *) &chat_macros[8], (int) HUSTR_CHATMACRO8 },
    {"chatmacro9", (int *) &chat_macros[9], (int) HUSTR_CHATMACRO9 }

};
```

Is this an incompatibility with modern compilers? Has anyone managed to get passed it?

Comment: Are you compiling it on 64-bit? It looks like `int` is smaller than the pointer type.

Comment: Post some excerpts from the code where these errors are located so we don't have to download sources just to answer your question..

Comment: @Mysticial Yes, should I try changing it to `long`?

Comment: @KBart this is the line in question:  {"sndserver", (int *) &sndserver_filename, (int) "sndserver"},

Comment: If you want, try this one source:
https://github.com/aserebryakov/sdl_doom
It uses SDL library to run. Not finished.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using 64-bit compiler, try to use the `-m32` flag and link with `-L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/` for 32-bit libraries.

By the way, if you will compile this source, you will still have an issue with running as this build needs 320x200 screen resolution. Otherwise it will not run.

I am working on the SDL port of the DOOM, so you can try my source from the [GitHub](https://github.com/aserebryakov/sdl_doom).

You will need to install SDL library to run it. Also, there is no sound there.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try your version. Will it work on a 64-bit system? or do I have to use 32-bit libraries?

Comment: @panos2point0 it still uses the 32-bit libraries. The main idea was to replace X11 code.

Answer (score 2):

As for the initializer list error, it's right there - the elements in the initializer lists are not constant expressions. Take a look at this:

```
{"mousedev", (int*)&mousedev, (int)"/dev/ttyS0"},
```

I guess `mousedev` is another variable. There you have it.

I can't remember now, but I think non-constants in initializer lists were introduced in one of the later C standards. Try making the compiler stick to a different one - I'd take a shot with C99.
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options

The one about integer vs pointer size was correctly answered by Alex.

Comment: What you are saying about the non-constant expressions makes perfect sense. I just wonder how this code worked for them in the first place. I am pretty sure this was written before the C99 standard.

Comment: Compilers used to be more lenient, you know. ;) GCC for instance has improved *heaps and bounds* in the last 10-20 years.